# Save Matlab GUI as vector graphics

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, vector-graphics, matlab-guide

I would like to present my Matlab GUI in a big poster, so I would like to safe it as a vector graphic and not just take a screenshot.

Is there an easy way to do that?

I am using matlab 2014a on OSX Mavericks

Comment: Have you tried google?  First hit is http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401-scalable-vector-graphics--svg--export-of-figures which looks like what you want

Comment: I did, however I am looking for something much easier than what this toolbox provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a gui in matlab， you must have a matched *.fig file

Then you can use

```
fig=openfig('mygui.fig');
print(fig,'-dpdf','test.pdf')
```

or

```
fig=openfig('mygui.fig');
saveas(fig,'test.pdf')
```

Also you can control very options like

```
fig=openfig('mygui.fig');
fig.InvertHardcopy = 'off';  %background
set(fig,'PaperPositionMode','auto'); % size position
print(fig,'-dpdf','test.pdf')
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks - I have just tried it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/print.html) command and one of the **EPS** formats (`-deps`, `-depsc`, `-deps2` or `-depsc2`).

**EDIT**

Here is a simple example using `gcf` to get the handle of the current figure:

```
print(gcf,'-deps','test.eps') % using EPS format
print(gcf,'-dpdf','test.pdf') % using PDF format
```

Comment: Also make sure you read the section "Printing MATLAB GUIs" of the `print` documentation.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example? What do I have to do before using for example: print('-depsc','-tiff','-r300','picture1')

Comment: I can print a certain part of the GUI, but it does not work with the whole GUI...

Comment: I have added a couple of simple examples. What is it that doesn't get printed?

Comment: gcf unfortunetly only opens a new figure, even if the GUI is already open. I open the GUI and saved the handle. Still I only get the left down part, so only a quarter of the full image

Comment: Then I don't know. Without seeing the actual GUI, it's difficult to comment any further why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `saveas` ?

Example: `saveas(hFig,'filename','format');` and then save to any available vectoric format such as .emf ([link to saveas doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)).